# How references in C++ are implemented with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've heared that C++ reference variables are implemented using pointers. I've been looking at some C code a while before i started with C++, I would because of that like to have something which i can relate to in the C language. Does anyone actually have an example on how it is implemented using pointers?

I've been doing some research on the question, this is what i've found. However, i'm not sure if it is legit or not as i've not been able to run this properly in a C++ file before. Any answers will be appreciated, thanks! :)

```
int& =  *(int const *)
```

Comment: That's not valid C++ and, even if it were, it would say _nothing_ about the _implementation_ of references. I'm not sure what sort of "example" you're looking for, other than links to huge chunks of (say) the GCC codebase?

Comment: If you think of `int& x` as `int* x` and mentally substitute `*x` wherever you see `x`, that would give you a rough approximation.

Comment: In c++ just use reference `&` declarations whenever possible, you don't need to care about the pointers behind then.

Comment: references are internally same as pointers, but have a bit different usage. references cannot be changed (the value they 'point to' can). that is the difference (and operator usage, you work on referenced object with reference, you have to use `*p` or `p->` with pointers).

Comment: @firda: Your comment simply begs the question. i.e. the OP knows what you just said already and is asking _how_ "references are internally [the] same as pointers" (which is not necessarily true, by the way).

Comment: Implementation-details are an implementation-detail. Most of the time, you can simply ignore them. Also, there is no guarantee any variable (like a reference) will actually physically exist.

Comment: Does this help? [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: well, canot see how is my answer different from NPE's, really. BTW: Not pointers? There can be only one differenc I can think of: compiler won't have so much 'aliasing problems' with references so they can optimize better.

Comment: @firda: It's quite different from NPE's, but you have to look closely to spot the difference. He's making an analogy to what the compiler does; in your comment you're just explaining how to use references.

Comment: @Light  No it isn't, you are just blind. We both said that the only difference is in operators used, not in the underlying structure. This is not the first time I have seen you commenting in a sense "this question cannot be answered" and downvoting those that try. I don't like you and have good reason for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference has the same meaning as a constant pointer.

The code for references and pointers is the same, at least with MSVC2013.

For example:

```
int u=1,v=3, w;

int& x = u;     // initialize reference 
w = x;          // x is synonym for u;
x++;    

int *y = &u;    // initalize pointer
w = *y;         // y points to u 
(*y)++;
```

The initialisation generates in both case:

```
lea eax, DWORD PTR _u$[ebp]
mov DWORD PTR _x$[ebp], eax    ; of course in the case of the pointe _y$ instead of _x$.
```

The assignment, in both case generates:

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
mov ecx, DWORD PTR [eax]
mov DWORD PTR _w$[ebp], ecx
```

And even the increment generates the same code.

The code generated is the same for whether it is a pointer, a const pointer, or a poitner to const (in the latter case, the ++ does not work).  It's the compiler buisness to make sure that const is const.

Now there is a subtle difference in syntax:

```
int& x = u;         // initialize reference 
int *y = &u;        // initalize pointer
int const *z = &u;  // initialize pointer to "const int".  Pointer itself is not const ! 
int * const a = &u;  // initialize "const pointer" to "int", which is basically a reference.
```

With these definitions:

```
//(*z)++;           // invalid because the it points to a const int. 
z = &w;             // valid because pointer intself is not const
```

and:

```
(*a)++;         // valid because the it points to an int.
// a = &w;      // invalid because it's a const pointer
```

So you could say `int&`  is pretty much equivalent to `int * const`  (I don't use '='  here, because it is reserved to the operator= and looks like a syntax error !)

Of course,  with the reference you always use its name as if it was a real variable (ex: `x++`)  while with the const pointer you always have to dereference (aka: `(*x)++`).  So same meaning, but different syntax.

Comment: +1 for machine code and correctly deciphering the last line of the question (edited btw) with a comment why it was (could have been) misleading

Answer (score 2):

This is the best *proof* I can think of:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double value;
struct pointer {
    double *value; };
struct reference {
    double& value; };

int main() {
    pointer ptr { &value };
    reference ref { value };
    *ptr.value = 3.14;
    cout << sizeof(value) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(pointer) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(reference) << endl;
    cout << ref.value;
}
```

Output:

```
8
4
4
3.14
```

Can you see the sizes? `sizeof(pointer) == sizeof(reference)` but not `sizeof(value)`.

Regarding that added/edited example in the question `int& =  *(int const *)`:

```
ref.value = *ptr.value; ref.value = *(double*)ref.value; //no const
ref.value = *(double const *)ptr.value; // yes, we can add const before *

int i = 1; const j = 2;
const int& cri = *(const int const *)&i; // same as *&i and simple i, notice two consts
const int& crj = j;
int& rj = j; // error: const cannot be removed that way
```

**In other words:** References are **constant** pointers (cannot be changed) with a different set of operators. The main advantage is that compilers can optimize them better (discard the ***reference/pointer*** completely), but that does not proof that they are any different because compilers can optimize/discard pointers as well (and gcc -O3 can do that well, I have seen and dissassembled good loop with pointers, where gcc could overcome so called ***aliasing problem***).

Answer (score 2):

A compiler can implement references any way that works, including that some references are completely optimized away.

You can *think* of the reference

```
T& r = o;
```

as

```
T* const pr = &o;
#define r (*pr)
```

which serves as a nice explanation of most properties of lvalue references, except that this conceptual picture does not include lifetime extension of temporaries and initialization with a temporary.

It “explains” that

- a reference must be initialized in the declaration, except when it’s a formal argument,
- a reference can’t be reassigned,
- a reference can’t be a “null-reference” in valid code.

But keep in mind that it’s *only* a conceptual picture: while it’s very likely to be the underlying reality for much of the generated code, it is by no means a requirement that a compiler implements a reference this way.

---

You might find the [section about references in the C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references) instructive.

Answer (score 0):

In C, when you use a variable as a parameter to a function, it is sent by value. If the function is supposed to change the variable, then the parameter must be sent as a pointer.

```
int x = 5;

void addtwo(int* param)
{
  *param += 2;
}

addtwo(&x); // This will send a pointer to x to the function addtwo
```

In C++, you can send a reference:

```
void addtwo(int& param)
{
  param += 2;
}

addtwo(x); // This will send a reference to x to the function addtwo
```

This doesn't look like much of a difference in this simple example, but in the second one, it *looks* like param is not being dereferenced. But it actually is, since it was sent as a reference. Even though `param` does not look like a pointer (and it isn't - it's a reference) the function `addtwo` is sent the address of x, very much as if it were a pointer. The difference is subtle, but concrete.

Comment: -1: All true, but you didn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Well I did show a comparison of logic using a pointer vs using a reference.

Comment: just delete the post if you worry about reputation and forget. the question was poorly worded, author said *Any answers will be appreciated* and moderators are often just prudent ;)

Comment: It's a bit better now.

Comment: Thanks. At this point improving this answer is an exercise in formulating an answer of reasonably good quality to the original question.